# Django (django-rest-framework) looking for a best practice to find out wether request.user exists in blog.likes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For simplicity's sake, lets say that i have the following models in a Django (django-rest-framework) application.

```
User (id, name)

BlogPost (id, user, content, image)

BlogPostLikes(id, user, blogpost, timestamp) 
// Assuming an inverse-relation to BlogPost via a variable called "likes"
```

I am looking for a "best-practice" kind of way to:

- fetch all blogs
- add a boolean flag for each blog indicating whether i as a user has liked that post.

Efficiently!

My intuition makes me want to implement it like this (using generic class-based views)

```
// views.py
class BlogPostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        return super(BlogPostList, self).get(...)


// serializers.py
class BlogPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = someUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    likes = BlogPostLikesSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ("id", "user", "likes", "content", "image")

class BlogPostLikesSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    blogpost = BlogPostSerializer()
    user = SomeUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPostLikes
        fields = ("id", "user", "blogpost", "timestamp")
```

But then I am stuck. I have no idea how to modify my `BlogPostLikesSerializer` to indicate wether the current user (`request.user` from `views.py`) is included in the likes set if a BlogPost. Do you guys have any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a two ways to achieve this.

1. If you just need a `boolean` `True`/`False` whether the `Post` is liked by the `request.user`, you can use `.extra`.

   1.1. Alter your `BlogPost` `Queryset` to something like this:

   ```
   class BlogPostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
       def annotate_is_liked_by_user(self, user):
           return self.extra(
               select = {'is_liked': 'EXISTS( \
                   SELECT `id` FROM `blogpostlikes` \
                   WHERE `blogpostlikes`.`blogpost_id` = `blogpost`.id \
                   AND `blogpostlikes`.`user_id` = %s)' % user.id
               }
           )

   class BlogPost
       # other stuffs here
       objects = BlogPostQuerySet.as_manager()
   ```

   1.2. Alter `get_queryset` method inside `BlogPostList` view

   ```
   class BlogPostList(ListAPIView):

       def get_queryset(self):
           user = self.request.user
           return BlogPost.objects.annotate_is_liked_by_user(user)
   ```

   1.3. Add the new field to the `BlogPostSerializer`

   ```
   class BlogPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
       # ....
       is_liked = serializers.BooleanField(source='is_liked')
       # ...
   ```
2. Get the whole `BlogPostLike` object.

   2.1.Alter the `get_queryset` method.

   ```
   class BlogPostList(ListAPIView):

       def get_queryset(self):
           user = self.request.user
           return BlogPost.objects.prefetch_related(
               Prefetch(
                   'likes', 
                   queryset=BlogPostLikes.objects.filter(user=user) \
                       .select_related('user'), 
                   to_attr='likes_by_request_user'
               )
           )
   ```

   2.2. Alter the `serializer`. But this can be done in two ways:

   2.2.1. Serializing a list with one item inside:

   ```
   class BlogPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
       # ...
       likes_by_request_user = BlogPostLikesSerializer(many=True)
   ```

   and remove the `blogpost = BlogPostSerializer()` from `BlogPostLikesSerializer`. I think this can lead to infinite loop.

   2.2.2 Serialize a single object:

   ```
   class BlogPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
       # ...
       like_by_request_user = BlogPostLikesSerializer(source='get_last_like', required=False)
   ```

   but this way you will have to add a new method inside your `BlogPost` object to return this single `Like` object

   ```
   class BlogPost(models.Model):
       #...
       def get_last_like(self):
           if hasattr(self, 'likes_by_request_user') and len(self.likes_by_request_user) > 0:
               return self.likes_by_request_user[0]
           return None
   ```

Comment: This solution seems is way more efficient than what i had planned. Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SerializerMethodField to get your flag dynamically, like this:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = SomeUserSerializer()
    likes = BlogPostLikesSerializer()
    has_liked = SerializerMethodField("get_has_liked")
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPostLikes
        fields = ("id", "user", "likes", "content", "image", "has_liked")

    def get_has_liked(self, obj):
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        return len([l.user.id == user.id for l in obj.likes]) > 0
```

However, you'd need to pass the request when instantiating your serializer, by doing something like this: `serializer = BlogPostSerializer(context={'request': request})`

Comment: Thanks, I actually considered this. It feels a little hacky though. Also, if I fetch 100 posts, this would require 100 additional lookups right (1 'contains check' for each post)? In raw sql I would try to perform some kind of join to achieve this